# What is the velocity of a photon through space-time? What is the 4-velocity of a photon?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, relativity, spacetime-dimensions

What is the velocity of a photon through space-time?  What is the 4-velocity of a photon?

Comment: It all depends on what direction it's going. The magnitude of the velocity is $c$.

Comment: @BillN is the magnitude of the photon's velocity through spacetime equal to c?

Comment: Said by physicist Brian Greene, all matter moves through space-time at "c". Thus if one is at true rest in space, one is in motion through time at the "c" magnitude of motion. Imagine a meson that is at rest in space and is in motion through time only, and then it decays into two photons. There seems to be a sudden 90° change in direction, going from motion across time, to motion across space. If this is not the case, motion is then across space-time at a "c * sqrt(2)" motion magnitude. As a side effect of this, the photons would appear to have zero mass. Does this help expand your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the four velocity for anything travelling at the speed of light (i.e. any massless particle) is that we define the four velocity using the proper time $\tau$. If we choose some coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ then the four velocity in our coordinates is:

$$ \mathbf U = \left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}, \frac{dx}{d\tau}, \frac{dy}{d\tau}, \frac{dz}{d\tau}\right) $$

The problem is that the proper time $\tau$ is the elapsed time in the rest frame of the moving object, and photons don't have a rest frame so the proper time is not defined. That means the four velocity is not defined either.

There are some workarounds. The four velocity is the tangent vector to a world line, and null or indeed spacelike world lines still have tangent vectors. But we'd have to write the four velocity using some affine parameter not the proper time and this isn't terribly useful.

Alternatively you could consider the behaviour as the speed tends towards $c$. You find that the norm of the four velocity stays equal to $c$ but the components of the four vector tend towards infinity.

Comment: The magnitude of the 4-velocity of every object through spacetime is c, except for photons, whose 4-velocity is not c through spacetime. Thus, is it true that all objects move at the velocity of light through spacetime, except for photons and light?

Comment: You write, "Alternatively you could consider the behaviour as the speed tends towards c."  So are you saying that because photons move AT the velocity of light, relativity fails to physically describe and grasp the photon?

Comment: @girlphysicsmajor no, I'm just saying that the four velocity isn't defined for photons. That doesn't mean relativity doesn't describe them. Of course it does. For example the photon four momentum is well defined.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77335/discussion-on-answer-by-john-rennie-what-is-the-velocity-of-a-photon-through-spa).